# All cached but a partial in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a template within my project wich is cached with a partial call inside:

```
<h1>My template</h1>
<?php include_partial('my_partial)?>
```

I don't want to cache the partial because it depends on the user. Is this possible?

I tried to disalbe the partial's cache without success:

```
//myModule/config/cache.yml
action:
  enbabled: true
_my_partial:
  enabled: false
```

The other solution that should work is to call the partial with an user dependant sf_cache_key:

```
<h1>My template</h1>
<?php include_partial('my_partial',array('sf_cache_key'=>$id_user)) ?>
```

But with a lot of users it will overload the cache because each user will have it's own version stored.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is inside `cache: enabled` key-value pairs ? I believe, the proper config should be:

```
//myModule/config/cache.yml
action:
  enabled:    true
_my_partial:
  enabled:    false

all:
  enabled:     false
  with_layout: false   # Default value
  lifetime:    86400   # Default value
```

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your `cache.yml`

```
_my_partial:
  enabled:    on
list:
  enabled:    on
...
```

it's `enabled: on` and not `cache: enabled.`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I wrote it from memory but I had it properly written on my code